# Shared import in Python

Tags: python

My program is getting quite big, I want to streamline it and put all my setup/constants in one file. For example, in C it's common to have a file which contains all constants and imports so you don't have to import a library in every file. Yet I haven't figured out how to do this in Python.

I want to do something like this:

setup.py

```
import requests
import json
URL = "url/"
```

file1.py

```
import setup #this is the part i'm not sure how to do
#everything is already setup
body = json.dumps({"this":False})
r = requests.put(URL + "request1", data=body)
# do stuff
```

file2.py

```
import setup #this is the part i'm not sure how to do
#everything is already setup
body = json.dumps({"this":True})
r = requests.put(URL + "request2", data=body)
# do stuff
```

Is there a way to do this? If not, what is the standard?

Comment: You can do that, but then you have to do e.g. `body = setup.json.dumps(...)`, or use wildcard imports (discouraged). Also it's harder to see for each file *what imports it's actually using*. There is no value to avoiding repeated imports; Python caches them anyway.

Comment: Maybe you want `from setup import *`? But that's actually not a good practice for imports -- it doesn't help performance, and makes individual source files harder to analyze for correctness in isolation if someone has to refer to somewhere else to know what your imports &c are.

Comment: ...aside: `setup.py` is a name that's conventionally used for your distutils/setuptools configuration. Reusing it for a different purpose is likely to confuse folks.